# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

I get an error when I open the file after it is created

```
using (var myFileStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            myFileStore.CreateFile(DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".txt");
        }
using (var myFileStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            temp = myFileStore.GetFileNames();
            for (int k = 0; k < temp.Length; k++)
            {
                IsolatedStorageFileStream file1 = myFileStore.OpenFile(temp[k], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                dataSource.Add(new SampleData() { Name = temp[k], Size = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(file1.Length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) + " MB") });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is due to the fact you didn't close the stream returned by the `CreateFile` method!

Your code should look like this:

```
using (var myFileStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    myFileStore.CreateFile(DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".txt").Dispose();
}
```

or

```
using (var myFileStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using(myFileStore.CreateFile(DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".txt"))
    {
    }
}
```

And the same in the OpenFile below.

Bottom line you should **always** dispose your stream (by using the `using` clause or `Dispose()` method)