# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream - WP7 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, mobile-application

I know this question has been asked many times, but I have almost tried everything but got no luck. So please help.

Some global variables:

```
private string _DirectoryForLogin = "LoginFiles", _FileForLogin = "Login.startup";
private IsolatedStorageFile _GlobalAccessRight = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
```

_DirectoryForLogin stores the name of the directory that stores login info and _FileForLogin stores txt file saved as .startup(I do not think this is the problem).

Later after InitializeCompolnent() I am doing this:

```
using(_GlobalAccessRight){
            //Checking if directory exists; case when user had already been logged in.
            if (_GlobalAccessRight.DirectoryExists(_DirectoryForLogin))
            {
                //Check if login startup file is already created.
                if (_GlobalAccessRight.FileExists(_DirectoryForLogin + "\\" + _FileForLogin))
                {
                    //Not of much concern for you people.
                    _UserNameLabel.Text = "Please wait.... Logging in.";
                    _UserNameHolder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
                    _UserNameHolder.IsEnabled = false;
                    _PasswordLabel.Text = "";
                    _PasswordHolder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
                    _PasswordHolder.IsEnabled = false;
                    _LoginButton.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
                    _LoginButton.Content = "";
                    _LoginButton.IsEnabled = false;

                }
                else
                    _GlobalAccessRight.CreateFile(_DirectoryForLogin + "\\" + _FileForLogin);
                //This part basically only creates the file, if directory was already existing.
            }
            else
            {
                    //Creates directory as well as file.
                    _GlobalAccessRight.CreateDirectory(_DirectoryForLogin);
                    _GlobalAccessRight.CreateFile(_DirectoryForLogin + "\\" + _FileForLogin);

            }
        }
```

Things were working fine till now. Problem is that if I try to delete the directory anywhere after creating directory, it sends me an error: "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorage." But I resolved it for time being by just closing my emulator all the time so that I get a fresh IsolatedStorage location.

Next I am taking input from the user in the text and password boxes, and writing them on a file above through this code:

```
        using(_GlobalAccessRight){
            //I have also tried by giving the FileShare argument below.
            using(IsolatedStorageFileStream WritingStreamForLoginInfo = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(_DirectoryForLogin + "\\" + _FileForLogin, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, _GlobalAccessRight)){
                using(StreamWriter WritingLoginInfo = new StreamWriter(WritingStreamForLoginInfo)){
                    String _LoginCredentials = "UserName: ";
                    _LoginCredentials += _UserNameHolder.Text;
                    _LoginCredentials += "\n";
                    _LoginCredentials = "Password: ";
                    _LoginCredentials += _PasswordHolder.Password;

                    //I added this afterwards. Before it was not here. And still it was not working.
                    WritingLoginInfo.Flush();
                    WritingLoginInfo.Write(_LoginCredentials.ToCharArray(), 0, _LoginCredentials.Length);
                    WritingLoginInfo.Close();
                    WritingStreamForLoginInfo.Close();
                }//End of 1st using clause
            }//End of second using clause
        }//End of third using clause
```

The above writing code is executed in the function that is executed on a Tap event of a Login button.
The code is sending this error:
Store must be open for this operation.

Exception detail:

System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled

Message=Store must be open for this operation.

StackTrace:

```
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)

   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, IsolatedStorageFile isf)

   at SafeMessenger.MainPage._LoginButton_Tap(Object sender, GestureEventArgs e)

   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)

   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Now one last thing that I should tell you people. Before I was doing like, creating a separate IsolatedStorageFile object for each thing. That is in above code, and in directory creation code. At that time I was getting this error:
"Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorage."

Right now I tried to go through the debug details of various variables and I found this which could be of some help for you people. Remember _GlobalAccessRight is a global private variable of IsolatedStorageFile type.

Quota 'this._GlobalAccessRight.Quota' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' long {System.ObjectDisposedException}

Kindly help me with this. Thank you for your time and any help, in advance. It would be a great help.

Comment: Isolated storage is A PAIN to deal with! The errors are VERY ambiguous. If you don't find a solid answer for this try my FREE dll EZ_Iso. It serializes all your stuff for you in a single call. You can do custom objects and even images. Go check it out. VERY easy to use http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after reading and thinking a lot I have finally got my code working on my own.
First the errors that operation not permitted were raised because of my bad handling of streams.

First I changed these lines:

```
.
.
.
}
 else
     _GlobalAccessRight.CreateFile(_DirectoryForLogin + "\\" + _FileForLogin);
            //This part basically only creates the file, if directory was already existing.
}
else
    {
        //Creates directory as well as file.
         _GlobalAccessRight.CreateDirectory(_DirectoryForLogin);
         _GlobalAccessRight.CreateFile(_DirectoryForLogin + "\\" + _FileForLogin);
    }
```

To:

```
.
.
.
}
 else
     _GlobalAccessRight.CreateFile(_DirectoryForLogin + "\\" + _FileForLogin).Dispose();
            //This part basically only creates the file, if directory was already existing.
}
else
    {
        //Creates directory as well as file.
         _GlobalAccessRight.CreateDirectory(_DirectoryForLogin);
         _GlobalAccessRight.CreateFile(_DirectoryForLogin + "\\" + _FileForLogin).Dispose();
    }
```

The second mistake was this:
I globally declared the IsolatedStorageFile object. After using it in my First using block:

```
using(_GlobalAccessRight){
        //Checking if directory exists; case when user had already been logged in.
        if (_GlobalAccessRight.DirectoryExists(_DirectoryForLogin))
        {
```

.
.
.
.
It got disposed at the end of it.
Therefore when I used it again in the function:

```
using(_GlobalAccessRight){
        //I have also tried by giving the FileShare argument below.
        using(IsolatedStorageFileStream WritingStreamForLoginInfo = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(_DirectoryForLogin + "\\" + _FileForLogin, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, _GlobalAccessRight)){
            using(StreamWriter WritingLoginInfo = new StreamWriter(WritingStreamForLoginInfo)){
                String _LoginCredentials = "UserName: ";
```

.
.
.
 it threw me error stating:
"Store must be open for that."

So I changed it to be this:

```
using(_GlobalAccessRight = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()){
        using(IsolatedStorageFileStream WritingStreamForLoginInfo = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(_DirectoryForLogin + "\\" + _FileForLogin, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, _GlobalAccessRight)){
            using(StreamWriter WritingLoginInfo = new StreamWriter(WritingStreamForLoginInfo)){
                String _LoginCredentials = "UserName: ";
```

Thats it! Bravo! :)

Comment: Some of the help was taken from this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584813/operation-not-permitted-on-isolatedstoragefilestream

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove these two lines:

```
WritingLoginInfo.Close();
WritingStreamForLoginInfo.Close();
```

`using` block supposed to open and close/dispose stream automatically. Maybe the error "Store must be open for this operation" caused by the code trying to close already closed connection at the end of `using` block.

Comment: Nothing changed after that too. Brother this part of code is never run. It is the second using statement that is throwing this error. No code is run beyond it.